# Extract a piece of a string in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, cut

I have following string in BASH and I need the email address at the end of the line

```
TAG instance    i-1846f265  AdminEmail  dummy.email@domain.com
```

As far as I know the spacing between the words is always a single tab character, the email address at the end does not have a fixed length (could be one of any number of addresses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` for this purpose:

```
$ cut   -f4                -d$'\t'                  your_file
         print 4th field    set tab as delimiter
```

Shorter:

```
$ cut -f4 -d$'\t' your_file
```

in case it is a string,

```
$ echo "your_strin" | cut -f4 -d$'\t' your_file
```

Answer (score 4):

`cut -f4` should work.  If it's a file, `cut -f4 file`.  If it's a string, `cut -f <<<"$string"`

Comment: fedorqui only just beat you to it so up votes for both of you :)

Comment: sigh, thanks for not using a pipe at least, but the external process is still completely unnecessary. For that matter, `<<< $(echo $string)` is entirely redundant.

Comment: @kojiro redundant how?  Can you explain?

Comment: @ExplosionPills certainly. `<<< "$string"` will redirect the value of `$string` to standard input. `<<< $(echo $string)` will echo the value to standard output, which will be captured in a subshell and then *that* will be redirected to the standard input. It should just be `<<< "$string"`.

Answer (score 3):

If it is in a script then this (just bash, no external stuff) works

```
line='TAG instance    i-1846f265  AdminEmail  dummy.email@domain.com'
set -- $line

echo "email address is " $5
```

There are numerous ways of splitting up a line like this.  `cut` as mentioned, `awk`, `sed`

Comment: or you can leave your positional parameters alone and just use an array: `line=( TAG instance    i-1846f265  AdminEmail  dummy.email@domain.com ); echo "${line[@]: -1}"`

Answer (score 0):

If the column number is uncertain, making cut unreliable, you can do a regexp grep on something that looks like an email.

```
echo "TAG instance    i-1846f265  AdminEmail  dummy.email@domain.com" | grep -o -e "[._a-zA-Z0-9-]\+*@[._a-zA-Z0-9-]\+"
```

Comment: -1 Using grep and a pipe introduces a subshell, plus `-o` is a nonstandard extension to `grep`. All of this is eminently doable with bash and there's just no reason to spawn two extra processes.

Comment: Grep can be used directly on a file. The echo with pipe was just to show an example of how to use it. Calm down a bit!

Comment: I'm not angry, just pointing out an objective technical flaw. Don't take it personally. File or no file, internal bash commands are objectively a better solution for the question posed.

Comment: Better solution, not the only solution

Comment: You vote down alternative solutions that can be helpful. Let the person asking the question decide whether counting columns or looking for email addresses suits his problem. (Also the pipe was a demonstration of the solution, not the solution itself. Not that it really matters).

Comment: @Atle in this case I don't see how `cut/awk/sed/grep` offer anything that is more useful than what bash can do internally. So I don't really think these alternative answers can be helpful as you say. I could be wrong, and can even be convinced by a sound argument, which, if it involves an edit, would cause me to remove my downvote.

Comment: @kojiro You're not the authority of what other people find helpful. The essence of my suggestion was using regexp to detect email instead of counting columns, which can be a better solution in cases where the number of tabs, spaces or columns are unpredictable. If grep is a bad way of detecting email, if my regexp is bad (it probably is), please suggest improvements. Running around being a self promoted authority of helpful answers, down voting anything you personally don't approve of, is just annoying people who try to be helpful.

Comment: For example, I found Kent's answer interesting, and learnt something new from it. Even if you couldn't condone his answer!

Comment: @Atle I'm only the authority of what *I* find correct and helpful, which is why I can only give one downvote per answer, and it causes me to lose reputation when I do so. I realize downvotes can seem offensive, though mine are only intended to point out technical flaws in answers. I also accept the directed annoyance I get from giving downvotes because I always leave my name and why I downvoted an answer, which is not required by SO.

Comment: It's not a problem because it's offensive, it's a problem because it's counter productive and goes against the core idea of this site; helping others. It's destructive and not helpful at all. Also you should consider the idea that even if you don't find an answer helpful, there might be something there you didn't consider. A solution might take into consideration something you, or even the poster, didn't consider.

Comment: Down vote suggestions that are wrong. Not suggestions that you don't personally favor.

Comment: @Atle but I *did* downvote suggestions that are wrong. It's wrong to introduce unnecessary processes and subshells where they aren't needed, just like it's wrong to spawn a perl process in the middle of a Python program to do something Python does natively. Will it work? Probably, but that's not the point: it's wrong because it introduces complexity and performance cost for no added value. Your argument that I may miss things is potentially valid, but academic unless you can tell me what I missed. What is the value here for subshells and UUoEs and external commands that makes them worthwhile?

Comment: I've told you what you missed already, the idea of using email detection instead of column counting. Do you have a suggestion to do that without using a tool that is not built into Bash? If you do, it would be infinitely much more helpful to share, than just complain about using grep. Also, the Unix-philosophy is using different tools and combining them to solve problems. The idea that that is wrong … is totally wrong. And it's not like there is a limitation to the times you can start a new process before you need to reboot the computer. The idea that you must avoid sub processes is wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

when I see "extract", I think of `grep`

```
grep -o '\S*$' file
```

Comment: -1 Using an external command with a nonstandard extension to do something bash does natively? I can't condone this.

Comment: so you meant any answers with `grep/cut/awk/sed/ack/...` are bad and deserve downvote?

Comment: I think @kojiro is downvoting all the answers, so don't worry Kent.

Comment: @Kent Until they are edited so they are optimal, yes. Sorry if I seem harsh, but just because an answer is popular doesn't make it right.

Comment: It might not be optimal, but still an answer, and a right one while at it. You don't go downvoting every non-optimal answer, the answer tag is used for that!

Comment: @fedorqui I am not worry about if he has downvoted others. I mean, if a question tagged `bash`, it doesn't mean it must be solved with pure bash. sometimes, "external tool" is more portable than bash script.

Comment: I agree, @OfirFarchy. We can dislike some answers, but downvoting is way too much if it is an answer that provides the solution of the question. A comment discouraging the use of external things should be enough. Anyway, I agree with Kent, the cut, grep solutions are quite easier to understand and learn.

Comment: No need to discourage anything. Offering different solutions to a problem can help the person see the problem in a different way and discover a better way to handle a given problem. It is also educational. Just offering improvements on answers would be much better.

Comment: @OfirFarchy That assumes the asker is the best qualified to judge the optimal answer. The asker is qualified to judge what works for him/her, but not necessarily the optimal one. Remember, these questions and answers are here for posterity!

Comment: Hence the comment you left should do the trick, it is also there for posterity

Comment: @kojiro up/downvote is your personal decision. it is ok. SO lives with it for so long time. btw, I commented your answer. (I didn't notice you answered the question) with a shell way, without using any commands, "internal" or "external".

Comment: @Kent it was a good comment. If you add it to this answer as an alternative solution I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @kojiro you are free to add it to your answer. since yours is kind of pure shell/bash. the downvote is ok. I believe you have your own opinion, though I don't think my answer deserves it.

Comment: @kojiro should put aside the idea that there are perfect answers. Different answers might consider different aspects of the problem. Sometimes these aspects are hidden, even to the poster himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the string into an array and drop all the fields before the end:

```
read -a fields <<< 'TAG instance    i-1846f265  AdminEmail  dummy.email@domain.com'
echo "${fields[@]: -1}"
dummy.email@domain.com
```

If the tab delineation is important, you can set `IFS=$'\t'` before read to guarantee wordsplitting on tabs.

Comment: how about `${x/#* /}` (x is the var with the string) if it is tab, then `${x/#*\t/}`

Comment: @Kent off the top of my head I think it'd need to be `$'\t'`, but the basic premise is right.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
echo $STRING | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

Or use `cut` as suggested above